# Jsoup parse some characters differently

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tried parsing this html file with Jsoup:

```
<html><body>Maître Corbeau, sur un arbre perché</body></html>
```

I used this line:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
```

When I try printing the document:

```
System.out.println(document.toString());
```

Both outputs:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Ma&icirc;tre Corbeau, sur un arbre perch&eacute;
</body>
</html>
```

Why did some of the characters change?

Comment: Because your input HTML is not properly encoded.

Comment: Please read documentation of readFileToString method. If you don't specify encoding it's going to be platform default. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @Smutje I added the charset="UTF-8" in the html but still same result.

Comment: @Jakub Hr I tried passing the file directly but it still outputs the same. So I think its not the readFileToString method.

Comment: Have you defined encoding when you've tried to parse directly from the file? Btw it's 1 minute to verify if your readFileToString works good with encoding parameter, so it's worth a try.

Comment: @JakubHr I verified that readFileToString works fine, anyways, now I just pass the file directly to the jsoup.parse method. still outputs the same. The characters seem to be encoded foreign characters of html.

Comment: What exactly is wrong about that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but why exactly is this the wrong output?

```
Ma&icirc;tre Corbeau, sur un arbre perch&eacute;
```

gives you

> Maître Corbeau, sur un arbre perché

in browser whitch is correct isnt it? if you want to get text with decoded content, you have to use `document.text()` insteed of `document.toString()` as the second one will give you the HTML output.
But remember, that you will loose all tag structure od HTML body.
If you really must have HTML code with decoded HTML entities, you will have to use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(input)` from `Apache Commons Lang`

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 was exactly what I needed